# javascript works in some browsers not others depending on environment

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari

I have a fairly simple javascript function that works on FF, IE and Chrome on my PC.  It also works on Chrome and IE on my MAC but doesn't work on Safari or FF on my MAC.  Here is the code:

```
function UpdateTot(row,column) {

    var r = row; 
    var c = column;
    var tabl = document.getElementById('SchedVenue');
    var l = tabl.rows.length;
    var cn = tabl.rows[0].cells.length;

    l--;
    cn--;

    var actcel = tabl.rows[r].cells[c];
    var cellct = tabl.rows[l].cells[c];
    var valct = cellct.innerHTML;
    var cellrt = tabl.rows[r].cells[cn];
    var valrt = cellrt.innerHTML;
    var cbg = actcel.bgColor;
    var bg = '';

    if (document.activeElement.checked)
    { 
        valct++;
        valrt++;
        bg = 'aqua';
    } else {
        valct--;
        valrt--;

        if(cbg == 'tomato') {
            bg='khaki';
            document.activeElement.disabled = true;
        } else {
            bg='white';
        }
    }

    if (valct != 3) {
        cellct.bgColor = 'tomato';
    } else {
        cellct.bgColor = 'white';
    }


    cellct.innerHTML = valct;
    cellrt.innerHTML = valrt;
    actcel.bgColor = bg;

    return;
}
```

When it DOESN'T work, it doesn't appear to recognize the  if (document.activeElement.checked) statement and ALWAYS decrements the counter.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, without seeing all of your code, but try using `this` instead of `document.activeElement`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried "this" with the same results - still doesn't work.  What you see is the entire javascript code.  The routine updates the row and column totals of a matrix when one of the cells is changed.  Following is the snipped of code that invokes the script.   echo '<td align="center" ' .$bg. '><input type="checkbox" value="yes" name=" '. $fname . '" 
    onClick="UpdateTot(' .$rn. ',' .$cn. ')" ' .$checked. ' ' .$disabled. ' />